# If $R$ is a symmetric and anti-symmetric relation on $A$, and $D$ is a diagonal in $A\times A$, then $R\subset D$, and $R\neq D$ in some cases.

Tags: logic, relations, proof-explanation, equivalence-relations

We know that if D is a diagonal in $A\times A$, that $D=\{(a,a)\in A\times A\}$. And $R$ is a relation on $A$, so $R = \{(a,b)\in A\times A}$. And since $R$ is symmetric and antisymmetric, then $aRb$ and $bRa$ and $a=b$, right?

I don't know if the proof is as easy as it seems, but can't you just say that
$R = \{(a,a)\in A\times A\}$ because $a = b$?

So what I'm stuck on is proving that $R \neq D$ as well and that $R = D$ doesn't have to be true for all cases, which is different than what my simple (yet probably incorrect) proof. So ya, I'm confused. Please help me.

Comment: Your first paragraph is fine though the wording could be a touch clearer. As a question, could the empty relation on $A$ be symmetric and anti-symmetric?

Comment: So it was actually given in the problem statement that R was both symmetric and anti-symmetric... if that was what you're asking?

Comment: I was asking what I asked.  Could the empty relation on $A$ be symmetric and anti-symmetric? If the answer is "no", then clearly the $R$ can't be the empty relation, but if the answer is "yes" then $R$ could be the empty relation which (if $A\neq\emptyset$) is certainly not equal to $D$.

Comment: Ok my fault, I clearly misunderstood the question. So, you're asking if (0,0) is symmetric and anti-symmetric then? The answer would be yes then because a = 0 and b = 0 correct? Making aRb symmetric and anti-symmetric? Is that the right logic? Then, a doesn't have to always equal b? So say b = 5, so (0,5) would exist in R but not in D.

Comment: I'm asking if $R = \emptyset\subseteq A\times A$ is a symmetric and anti-symmetric relation. That is, $(a,b)\notin R$ for all $a,b\in A$. Symmetry means $\forall a,b\in A.(a,b)\in R \implies (b,a)\in R$, but this is [vacuously true](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth#Scope_of_the_concept) since $(a,b)\notin R$. Similarly for anti-symmetry. So $\emptyset$ is always a symmetric and anti-symmetric relation.

Answer (score 0):

You are right in saying that if $R$ is symmetric and anti-symmetric on $A$, it doesn't follow that $R = D$.
That would be the case if $R$ were also reflexive.

As a minimal counterexample, let $A = \{0,1\}$ and $R = \{ (0,0) \}$.
Then $R$ is symmetric and anti-symmetric.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the simple explanation. :)

Comment: @JacobBarazoto By the way, Derek Elkins is right. If you don't exclude the empty set as a binary relation (I don't) then it is symmetric and anti-symmetric. So a truly minimal counterexample would be $A = \{0\}$ and $R = \varnothing$. Of course $R$ wouldn't be reflexive.